# Number of Yamim Tovim that fall on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, number, calendar, chagim-holidays

In a given year, a certain number of Yamim Tovim days fall on Shabbos, and a certain number not. What are the minimum and maximum count of Yamim Tovim days that can fall on Shabbos in a single year (Tishrei-Elul), in and out of Eretz Yisrael?

Comment: Why?​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @double aa Maybe he has to plan his vacation schedule and his boss asked him.

Comment: Basically what @SethJ said: the question was spawned by my wanting to be able to say "there will be up to n days spread throughout the year like Shabbos" on interviews. My field is web development, and in some positions 24-hour on-call coverage can be an issue.

Comment: @yitznewton So you are more interested in the min/max number of days that _aren't_ on Shabbat. (I know you can figure out how many are from how many aren't.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess so; I was treating the question as abstracted from my particular situation, and as such I phrased it in the way I thought clearest, i.e. removing negatives that are not necessary to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's denote a year by what day is the first day of Rosh Hashanah and what day is the first day of Pesach. So, for example, "2-3" means Rosh Hashanah on Monday and Pesach on Tuesday. For our purposes, years run from Tishrei through Elul.

We have to consider the following yomim tovim: **Rosh Hashanah**, for which we're provided the day of the week; **Yom Kippur**, which is two "week"-days after R"H; **Succos**, which is on the same day of the week as R"H; **Shmini Atzeres**, which is also on the same day of the week as R"H; **Pesach**, which we're provided; **Seventh day of Pesach**, which is first-day Pesach minus one; **Shavuos**, which is first-day Pesach plus one.

Now, for each possible year, I'll provide the R"H-Pesach numbers, and we'll calculate the rest:

- **2-3.** Nothing on Shabbos
- **2-5.** In Chutz La'aretz, second day of Shavuos is on Shabbos.
- **3-5.** same as 2-5.
- **5-7.** Yom Kippur is Shabbos, First day Pesach is Shabbos, and in Chutz La'aretz, Eighth day Pesach is Shabbos.
- **5-1.** Yom Kippur is Shabbos, Seventh day Pesach is Shabbos.
- **7-1.** Rosh Hashanah is Shabbos, Succos is Shabbos, Shmini Atzeres is Shabbos, Seventh day Pesach is Shabbos.
- **7-3.** Rosh Hashanah is Shabbos, Succos is Shabbos, Shmini Atzeres is Shabbos.

(The following occur only as leap-years.)

- **2-7.** First day Pesach is Shabbos, and in Chutz La'aretz, Eighth day Pesach is Shabbos.
- **3-7**. Same as 2-7.
- **5-3**. Yom Kippur is on Shabbos.
- **7-5**. Rosh Hashanah is Shabbos, Succos is Shabbos, Shmini Atzeres is Shabbos. In Chutz La'aretz, second day Shavuos is on Shabbos.

So, the most possible *yomim tovim* that occur on Shabbos in one year in Israel is **four**, which happens when R"H falls on Shabbos and Pesach on Sunday. In Chutz La'aretz, the most is also **four** in the same year and also when Rosh Hashana falls on Shabbos and Pesach on Thursday (which only occurs as a leap year).

Comment: If you ran the year Nisan-Adar, there are *many* fewer permutations.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, although Nissan is _rosh hashana lirgalim_ question states an Tishrei-Elul year

Answer (score 1):

In a non-leap year that starts on Monday and has 29 days in *Kislev*, no *yom tov* is *Shabas* in Israel or out of it. So zero days is the least.

In a non-leap year that starts on *Shabas* and has 29 days in *Kislev*, the first days of *Rosh Hashana*, *Sukos*, and *Sh'mini Atzeres* are *Shabas*, as is the seventh day of *Pesach*. No year has more, so four days is the most.

Source: tables (a perpetual calendar).

Comment: starts?  1 Nisan? 1 Tishrei? 1 Januray?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman 1 _Tishre_ of course.