# Sources for how many days of holidays are there per year?

Tags: calendar, chagim-holidays, chol-hamoed

Specifically, I am looking for a traditional source like the Baal Haturim. I overheard that a number that I don't remember, but basically like 49 days out of the year are holy days. Is there a mesorah on this?

So, I guess I should clarify. I was looking for a masora of 49 Yom Tovim in the style of the Baal HaTurim who usually gives a specific number in his lists like the number of names of Yisrael or Yerushalayim or the Torah even though there's probably more.

However, for the sake of argument, what is the maximal amount baEretz? B'chutz laEretz? Without Shabbat? With Shabbat?

I see in the comments that the absolute maximum Yom Tovim seems to be 105. What if one factors in other major holidays like Chanukah?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79097/759

Comment: Aren't there at least 52 days of Shabbat?

Comment: I don't understand the question - all the holidays are fixed, what sources you expect to hear - Like Rambam Zmanim? Do you expect Mesorah that's unconnected to Halachah? Go out and count it!

Answer (score 1):

H/t to DoubleAA for filling in the blanks. Outside of Eretz Yisrael in a non-leap year, there could potentially be 49 "holy days" (not counting Shabbos):

- 2 days of Rosh HaShanah
- 1 day of Yom Kippur
- 9 days of Sukkos
- 8 days of Chanukah
- 1 day of Purim
- 8 days of Pesach
- 2 days of Shavuos
- 17±1 days of Rosh Chodesh
- =47-49 holy days

Admittedly, this number is pretty arbitrary; even if you're not counting Shabbos (which is already arbitrary), the number could be as few as 44 (Eretz Yisrael in the shortest possible non-leap year) or as many as 51 (outside Eretz Yisrael in the longest possible leap year). This number can go up to 94-105 if you factor in Shabbasos, and even more if you redefine "holy day" (ex. days on which Tachanun isn't said, which itself is subject to varying customs).

So yes, it's *possible* for there to be 49 holy days on the calendar, but only under an arbitrary definition in a very specific scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to downvote since the OP was adamant that he needs a classical source

Comment: @DoubleAA He asked "is there a mesorah on this?" My classical source is the calendar, which was fixed in 4711 AM, based on principles that date back even further.

Comment: As to AA, are you saying that no rabbi has ever counted the number of holidays? It seems like that's the gantze tachlis of the Baal Haturim and others who are interested in gematria.

Comment: @Kfir I think he's saying that you asked for "traditional sources like the Ba'al HaTurim," which I didn't provide; hence my response above that I feel that I did. If you didn't specifically want such sources, you should probably take that out of your question (since it doesn't invalidate any existing answers).

Comment: @Kfar Plenty have, there's just no need to cite an expert for something you can verify in 5 minutes with a publicly available calendar

Comment: wouldn't this list also be subject to the definition of "holiday"? There are other days on the calendar on which we don't say tachanun (one measure) and not all of these days demand the same atmosphere of "holiday."

Comment: @rosends As I noted, it seems to be awfully arbitrary.